# Add previous button to vue-form-wizard tab content

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a vue form wizard (https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard)

Rather then having a previous button in the footer I need to add a button in the second tab-content content.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<tab-content title="second tab">
    <button @click="previousTab">Take me back to the previous tab</button>
</tab-content>
```

How do I add a previous button to my second steps content in StepForm.vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all you need is to give the `FormWizard` a ref. Then use that ref to access the `FormWizard` and in the button's click handler call the `prevTab()` method of the `FormWizard`

```
 <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete" 
                      shape="square"
                      color="#3498db" ref="formWiz">
            <tab-content title="Personal details"
                         icon="ti-user">
              My first tab content
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Additional Info"
                         icon="ti-settings">
              My second tab content
              <div>
              <button @click="goBack">GO BACK !</button>
              </div>
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Last step"
                         icon="ti-check">
              Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
            </tab-content>
</form-wizard>
```

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onComplete: function() {
      alert('Yay. Done!');
    },
    goBack() {
      this.$refs.formWiz.prevTab()
    }
  }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht8rjw5g/)